# how to add a top margin (CSS) to a custom menu item in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, image, menu

I have an avatar in my header (inserted with a shortcode as a custom menu item). Unfortunately it sits directly under the top of the container (header) and I can't figure out the CSS to nudge it down. I guess I need to use CSS `margin-top` but I don’t know how to correctly target the item.

In Chrome Inspector, this is where it's at:

```
#menu-lift-your-reading-main > #menu-item-3850 > a > img.avatar.avatar-90.photo.lazyloaded
```

(You can only see this avatar if you're logged in as it's for current user.)

All answers much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have a margin or padding on your body. Then the margin from the image has nothing to bounce against... it gets pushed outside the screen.

So instead of a margin-top on your image (child) add a padding-top to the parent element.

Bases on the CSS rule you gave, I'm guessing that this should do the trick:

```
#menu-lift-your-reading-main > #menu-item-3850 {
    padding-top: 1em;
}
```